# Removing blank item from List not working when referencing it in a query

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file that has tab delimited data within it. I pull this data row by row and split it. I then use it in a sql query to insert into a table. unfortunately some of these files have a trailing tab (tab after last column) which ofc is interpreted as another column. When this happens I get a error saying sql expected 16 parameters and got 17.

running Python 3. I have tried using list comprehension and filters. But its not working

```
....
for line in islice(OutputFile,int(Quantity)):
                data= line.split("  ")

                #The following line removes ALL values in the list that are empty. This is for the case where there is a trailing tab in the data
                data[:] = [val for val in data if val]
                query = ("INSERT INTO [smthn].[dbo].smthn] (Country,ChargingType,OrderNumber,foo,bar,foo,bar,foo,bar,foo,bar,foo,bar,foo,Date,bar) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
cursor.execute(query,int(CountryCode),ChargingType,OrderNumber,*data,str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),data[1][:18])
```

nb. Cursor.execute is a part of the For loop.. not sure why this thing isnt putting it in the loop.....

For the sake of company privacy I changed a bunch of naming above. If something is off with spacing or naming etc, please just take me at face value that it is correct in the actual code and i may have just missed it here when i changed up stuff.

Im supposed to receive the list with only 16 paramaters (as  i remove the blank item from the list) so i can be executed successfully in the insert query.

as stated above error msg is "The SQL contains 16 parameter markers, but 17 parameters were supplied'"

Comment: As a step to debugging, I would print the values that are sent to SQL query. Also a count of values would do a world of good. (Before executing the query). I don't think your algo is failing for all the lines, just need to analyze those lines more

Comment: I have a print setup and i tested through and was getting the extra parameter still. but when i run through my algo in idle it works fine so i dnt get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of trailing tabs by replacing `data= line.split("  ")` by:

```
data= line.strip().split("  ")
```

Comment: This worked so I selected as answer Thanks! But im still curious as to why my version did not work.. there may be a day someday when i cant strip all the columns for eg.

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually see the data. But if it's really tabbed it could be better to split on a tab.

```
data = line.strip().split('\t')
```

or if you want a list comprehension:

```
data = [i for i in line.strip().split() if i] # no need to specify "   " or '\t'
```

Comment: Thanks ivallesp came in with the answer first tho so i gave it to him. still would love to know why my version didnt work tho if u know.

PS. data is rlly tabbed i can see the tabs in notepad++/ultra edit etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove all trailing tab characters. r in rstrip is for right.

```
line.rstrip("\t").split("\t")
```

Or without rstrip you could slice up to 16th item inclusive with
[:17]
Instead of your 18.